# Prolog defining my own operator and arithmetic_function

Tags: prolog, operator-keyword

I wanna declare an ! operator who will used to calculete facorial of an Integer.

I have this code in file.

```
:- arithmetic_function(!/1).

!(X,Y):-sil(X,1,Y).
sil(0,X,X):-!.
sil(N,A,X):-A1 is A*N,N1 is N-1,sil(N1,A1,X).
```

And i use op(500,yf,!) to declare an operetor. Why this solution is not working i mean it looks like arithmetic_function didn't register my ! function.

when i try 5! i get

ERROR: Undefined procedure: (!)/1
ERROR:     However, there are definitions for:
ERROR:         (!)/0
ERROR:         (!)/2
false.

Answer (score 1):

You're simply forgetting that arithmetic in Prolog is introduced by means of is/2.

```
?- X is 6! + 1.
X = 721.
```